# How to prevent scrollview bouncing when adjusting content for keyboardWillBeShown/keyboardWillBeHidden

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I have a scrollview with a number of textfields, including some at the same Y position.  I'm using the following code to adjust the scrollview's offsets/insets so that the active textfield is always visible - but if the user is already editing a field and then taps on another textfield in that same "row" (same Y position) the scrollview bounces/readjusts.  Is there anyway to work around this?

```
- (void)keyboardWillBeShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    UIView *activeField = [self.view findFirstResponder];

    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    aRect.size.height -= aRect.origin.y;
    aRect.origin.y = 0;

    CGPoint activeFieldOrigin = [activeField convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.view.window];

    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeFieldOrigin) ) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeFieldOrigin.y-kbSize.height);
        [self.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

I can prevent the behavior by doing the setContentOffset:animated with animated=NO.  So I assume that with animated = YES it is kicking the actual work off to a block or delaying execution of the actual set and then when it /does/ actually go to do that, the re-show is immediately resetting it back to the same position.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the current contentoffset of scrollview like  contentOffsetY=_scrollView.contentOffset.y; and then check

```
if(contentOffsetY==_scrollView.contentOffset.y)
{
//then should not change scrollviews content offset
}
else
{
//change content offset
}
```